# Find Minimum Bounding Box for a set of coordinates

Tags: gps, extents

I am working with GPS tracks (lat/lon values) and my goal is to [compute the minimum bounding box](https://github.com/dret/GPXQuery/issues/3) for a [small geospatial library I am working on](https://github.com/dret/GPXQuery). The datasets are not huge, maybe a couple of tens of thousands of points. I could not find an algorithm that deals with tracks/datasets crossing from -180 to 180 lat or lon. Does anybody have pointers to algorithms?

To sum it up very simply, what I am looking for is:

- Input: (lat/long)* [possibly tens of thousands of GPS points, potentially crossing 180/-180 boundary)]
- Output: (lower-left, upper-right) of the minimal box containing all points

The background for me is that I need the bounding boxes to initialize map viewers, in particular when there is more than one track displayed on a map.

Comment: I was working on that atm. Also cgal libraryhas a solution for it in its API

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @nickves. I did find many library functions in various languages/toolboxes, but I want to implement it myself, so I need an algorithm and not a library function.

Comment: adding to my previous comment: i am **not** looking for the smallest possible rectangle, but for the minimum axis-aligned one (because it is supposed to be used as a viewport for map views).

Comment: in that case; you're looking the for the BBox. its a parallelogram with opposite corners at xmin,ymin and xmax,ymax.